# Concatenate two queries in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to split my long queries in mongodb for example instead using db.users.find(q) in the following code, I want to use a concatenate version like this db.users.find(q0+q1) or any other way that I can split q into two queries

```
q= {},{name:1,"education.school.name":1,"education.type":1} 
db.users.find(q)  
q0={}
q1={name:1,"education.school.name":1,"education.type":1}   
q=q0+","+q1 
db.users.find(q)
```

How do I do something like that?

Comment: What programming language are we talking about?

Comment: mongodb, not using any java code

Answer (score -1):

Your clauses are somewhat ambiguous there (your `q` and `q0` are both empty objects), but you might want the [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/) operator

```
db.users.find(
  $or: [
    {name:1,"education.school.name":1,"education.type":1},
    {age:1,"education.school.name":2,"education.type":2} 
  ]
)
```

This'll return the set union of those two queries. That said, depending on what you're actually wanting to do, you might be able to use `$in` with an array of values to search for per field, if you just want to search on multiple values.

Comment: but how having  q0={name:1,"education.school.name":1,"education.type":1} and q1={age:1,"education.school.name":2,"education.type":2}, how can use q0 and q1 in the db.users.find?

Comment: If you have two clauses, the `$or` is appropriate.

Comment: I tried db.users.find($or: [q0,q1]) where q0 and q1 the above queries, I tried a few combinations but none of them worked

Comment: Looks like you want to do db.users.find({'$or' : [q0, q1]}) as the complete query.  Also note that if you want the intersection of the results from q0 and q1 then you would want to use $and operator instead of $or

Comment: Sintax corret is

db.users.find( {
  $or: [
    {name:1,"education.school.name":1,"education.type":1},
    {age:1,"education.school.name":2,"education.type":2} 
  ]
})